# org.json with JavaME inserts random number in toString()

Tags: java, json, blackberry, java-me

I'm building an application for BlackBerry in Java and to read/write JSON I'm using the org.json.me package included in the SDK.

When I generate a complex JSONObject and run the toString() method on it to send the data I see a seemingly random number appear in the string which breaks the JSON

```
{"cb_aggregate_key":
  [
    {"$project":{"Symbol":"1","Price":"1","total":"1"}},
    {"$group":[8835.281] {"_id":"$Symbol","total":{"$sum":"$Price"}}}
  ]
}
```

Notice at the beginning of the $group object I have this [8835.281] which is not part of my object. I tried to log the toString() of the JSONObject inserted under the "$group" key and it looks correct

```
{"_id":"$Symbol","total":{"$sum":"$Price"}}
```

Initially I thought it could be some strange character in my strings but couldn't find anything.

Then I noticed that even when reading JSON responses from the http://cloudbase.io APIs I transform the string successfully to a JSONOjbect. When I then print out the output running the toString() method of the JSONObject I see random numbers appearing there too:

```
{"register-device":
  {
    "status":"OK",
    "message":{
      "output":"register 2013-01-31[8832.953] T13:49:41+00:00 553648138",
      "sessionid":"510a767592a578064d0001d2"
    },
    "error":""
  }
}
```

Notice the [8832.953] appearing in the "output" string.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before?

Comment: I've seen similar tags dumped to my eclipse plugin console output, nothing to worry about, it is just annoying. Your string is probably ok. Try logging the string length to make sure.

Comment: I did. It would seem these tags are just dumped in the string but I get an error back from the server saying that the character []... is not valid. Looks as though those are actually sent in my request.

exception: field p[2161.851] ath references must be prefixed with a '$' ('1'"}

Comment: This is now solved. You were right. The tags were only appearing in the debug output. The issue was that in the $project aggregate function I was putting the 1/0 for the fields to be included as strings rather than integers. Since they were string cloudbase.io was trying to read them as fields

Answer (score 2):

It's the unnecessary debug output in the console window in Eclipse which will output a timestamp in the following format every few milliseconds of execution:

`[12345.678]`

There is unfortunately no way to switch it off, although you could parse it out using a regular expression match.

Comment: but, in all likelihood, there's no need to parse it out.  the extra timestamp appears to just be part of his stdout logging.

Comment: Yes, I meant parse it out of the console log, not out of his code.

Comment: Yes. It turned outI was out on a wild goose chase. The issue was completely different and I was confused by the random numbers in the output